# Create string variable from value in dataframe field pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A query that I have not managed to find and I've been trying for a while, how can I pass the value of a dataframe to a string variable without inheriting that is of type object? This is because I need to concatenate in a text certain values of a dataframe.

Let me explain:

```
v_addres = df_example['Addres']
print("Addres is " + v_addres)
```

The result is approximate, but it adds values for me.

```
"0    Addres is .... Name: Addres, dtype: object"
```

How can I keep only the value of the field?

I want see some this:

```
"Addres is Av. Springfield 178."
```

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
if you make the example reproducible, i'll be able to share the resut

```
df_example['Addres'][0]
```